# Cookies broken in Vista (across many browsers)

Tags: browser, cookies

Starting last week, it seems cookies in my laptop stopped working. I'm unable to log on to any website, it just comes back to the login screen (Facebook) or says cookies need to be enabled (Gmail). I usually use Firefox and thought something was broken with it. But later I realized it has the same behavior in Chrome and IE.

Cookies are enabled and they work just fine in a site like this: http://www.html-kit.com/tools/cookietester/

We tried rebooting, there isn't an antivirus running, cleaning up the %TEMP% folder. I'm currently out of ideas on what to do next, except formatting.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/254835/cookies-enabled-but-actually-disabled#comment263632_254849 suggests checking your system time; is it set correctly?

Comment: Yes, the date / time is correct, set as January 27th 2013...

Comment: Hmm, it's hard to guess what could be wrong without more information. http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?locale=en_US&page=content&y=PROD_FIN&id=SLN2306 has a few troubleshooting steps.

Answer (score 0):

Check when the error happened relative to when Windows updated. Perhaps an update broke something.

In Windows Update, View Update History. If it's that, you can roll them back and retest.
You'll also see Fails that may break things.